# how to use one command line to calculate substration of two intergers as results from two other commands

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I'm running a bash script to output logs under a log directory. Initially I want to know how many logs are generated, simply do the following:

`ls logs | wc -l`

And as the bash script is running in real time, I can further use:

`watch -n 5 'ls logs | wc -l'`

to display the number of log files concurrently.

But I also know the total number of log files that should be generated by checking how many lines under a file called `file.txt` by:

`cat file.txt | wc -l`

Now I want to display how many more logs need to be generated by substracting the two numbers, I searched, there are several ways to do math in shell, e.g. using `expr` or use double brackets.
For example, assuming my total number of lines in `file.txt` are 1000.
If I hard code this into the command, the final command would be like

`watch -n 5 'ls logs | wc -l | xargs expr 1000 - '

But I want to substitute `1000` with the result coming from `cat file.txt | wc -l` command. I tried the following but not working. I'm not sure if `xargs` can accept two arguments from 2 commands, or this is not how we use it here.

`watch -n 5 'ls logs | wc -l | xargs expr "cat file.txt | wc -l" + '`

(Note: what if I only want to count number of lines in `file.txt` that not begin with a `#` letter and not an empty line? How do I do that here?) Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if `xargs` can accept two arguments from 2 commands.

It can run a command with multiple arguments spread across multiple lines from input. For example, this will tell `xargs` to run `expr` with three arguments taken from input (which are, in order, the number of logs, `-`, and the number of lines in `file.txt`):

```
(ls logs | wc -l; printf "%s\n" -; wc -l < file.txt) | xargs -n 3 expr
```

It might be more idiomatic to use **command substitution** here:

```
expr "$(ls logs | wc -l)" - "$(wc -l < file.txt)"
```

> [W]hat if I only want to count number of lines in file.txt that not begin with a # letter and not an empty line?

Count with `grep`:

```
grep -c -v -e '^#' -e '^$' file.txt
```

- `-c` to count matching lines
- `-v` to invert the match, so lines not matching the following are selected
- `-e '^#` to match lines beginning (`^`) with a `#`
- `-e '^$` to match lines which end (`$`) immediately after they begin (`^`),, i.e., they are empty.